# How to write Sequelize Model with Exisiting Table in MSSQL database

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I would like to create the model for existing table name from MSSQL database using Sequelize.

My model is under like - In user.js

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = model;

function model(sequelize) {
  const attributes = {
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    phone: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
    password: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    token: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  };

  const options = {
    defaultScope: {
      // exclude hash by default
      attributes: { exclude: ["hash"] },
    },
    scopes: {
      // include hash with this scope
      withHash: { attributes: {} },
    },
  };

  return sequelize.define("user_testing", attributes, options);
}
```

My existing table name is [testing].[user_testing].

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [userId]
      ,[name]
      ,[phone]
      ,[email]
      ,[image]
      ,[password]
      ,[token]
  FROM [testing].[user_testing]
```

I would like to create the model using existing table name [testing].[user_testing] and their column name.

Comment: And what stop you from indicating `tableName` and `schema` in the `options`?